# How to track software usage

Tags: software-recommendation, log

Is it possible (preferably via some package) to know how many times have I used software? All software. And maybe for how long? Also when was it last opened. The more provided info the better.

It's also preferable to get the output in a GUI.

Comment: Mostly(if not exactly) similar to [Application to show software usage on Linux?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1700/968).

Answer (score 1):

Zeitgeist is exactly what this is for. It is available from the Ubuntu Software Center and has been covered many times by OMGUbuntu.

Comment: ...well thanks a lot! really! but this program tracks files more than program usage but I still like it! :D ... anyways would you please edit in the installation procedures. I really had trouble with that.

Comment: I cannot find Zeitgeist in the Software Centre, it would be nice if you could provide a link.